# How can I trigger a response on a particular day in a month with condition tag?

Tags: aiml

I am having problems making my aiml chatbot respond on a particular day of the month.

I make chatbots on botlibre.
I tried this code in my aiml chatbot but it did not work.

```
<pattern>date</pattern>
<template>
<think><set name="day of the month"><date format="%B %d"/></set></think>
<condition name="day of the month">
<li value="December 29">it's the twenty ninth.</li>
<li value="November 06">it's the sixth. How are you?</li>
</condition>
```

The expected result is the twenty ninth.
In actuality the aiml chatbot does not respond.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid AIML and should work. It works fine on Pandorabots.com

Amend your category (as below) so it displays your predicate and you can see what "day of the month" is set to. My advice is to miss out the spaces in the predicate name and set it to "dayofthemonth" or even just "day", as it's possible Botlibre doesn't like predicates with spaces.

```
<category>
    <pattern>date</pattern>
    <template>
        <set name="day of the month"><date format="%B %d"/></set>
        <condition name="day of the month">
            <li value="December 29">it's the twenty ninth.</li>
            <li value="November 07">it's the seventh. How are you?</li>
            <li>day of the month = <get name="day of the month"/></li>
        </condition>
    </template>
</category>
```

An AIML tip I would advise you do with <condition> is to always include a catchall <li> as I've done above. That way, your bot will at least respond with something if nothing matches rather than leaving the user hanging.

Comment: To just one word?